# Get and insert order email address to the PHP template inside HTML text

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, templates

I broke my head trying to solve the following case. I have a WooCommerce `admin-new-order.php` PHP template I want to customize. All I want is to add the order email address to the top of the email body inside the custom URL. I'll explain more detailed below:

I have the `<a href="https://dashboard.mywebservice.com/search?query=" target="_blank">https://dashboard.mywebservice.com/search?query=</a>` URL and I want to add this URL to the top of the PHP template.

I need to get the customer email address and insert it inside the URL so the URL will transform into (as an example):

```
<a href="https://dashboard.mywebservice.com/search?query=orderemail@gmail.com" target="_blank">https://dashboard.mywebservice.com/search?query=orderemail@gmail.com</a>
```

I guess I need to try to code something like that, but unfortunately I can't get of how to insert PHP  here instead of demo email address:

```
<p><?php printf( __( '<a href="https://dashboard.mywebservice.com/search?query=orderemail@gmail.com" target="_blank">https://dashboard.mywebservice.com/search?query=orderemail@gmail.com</a>' ); ?></p>
```

I would appreciate any help with this one.

Comment: Is your problem getting the email address, or escaping it and adding it into the string, or both?

Comment: @Rup the problem is global, I don't know how to get the email address and insert it to the <p>...</p>